# Google Cloud Buildpack custom source directory for Python app

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, buildpack

I am experimenting with Google Cloud Platform buildpacks, specifically for Python. I started with the [Sample Functions Framework Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpack-samples/tree/master/sample-functions-framework-python) example app, and got that running locally, with commands:

```
pack build --builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder sample-functions-framework-python
docker run -it -ePORT=8080 -p8080:8080 sample-functions-framework-python
```

Great, let's see if I can apply this concept on a legacy project (Python 3.7 if that matters).

The legacy project has a structure similar to:

```
.gitignore
source/
    main.py
    lib
        helper.py
    requirements.txt
tests/
    <test files here>
```

The `Dockerfile` that came with this project packaged the `source` directory contents without the "source" directory, like this:

```
COPY lib/ /app/lib
COPY main.py /app
WORKDIR /app
... rest of Dockerfile here ...
```

Is there a way to package just the *contents* of the `source` directory using the buildpack?

I tried to add this config to the `project.toml` file:

```
[[build.env]]
name = "GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE"
value = "./source/main.py"
```

But the Python modules/imports aren't set up correctly for that, as I get this error:

```
File "/workspace/source/main.py", line 2, in <module>
  from source.lib.helper import mymethod
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source'
```

Putting both `main.py` and `/lib` into the project root dir would make this work, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Related question, is there a way to see what project files are being copied into the image by the buildpack? I tried using verbose logging but didn't see anything useful.

---

Update:

The python module error:

```
File "/workspace/source/main.py", line 2, in <module>
  from source.lib.helper import mymethod
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source'
```

was happening because I moved the `lib` dir into `source` in my test project, and when I did this, Intellij updated the import statement in `main.py` without me catching it. I fixed the import, then applied the solution listed below and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had been searching the buildpack and Google cloud function documentation, but I discovered the option I need on the [pack build documentation page](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/cli/pack_build/): option `--path`.

This command only captures the `source` directory contents:

```
pack build --builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder --path source sample-functions-framework-python
```

If changing the path, the `project.toml` descriptor needs to be in that directory too (or specify with `--descriptor` on command line).